# Communication between Nodes

Tags: ros, communication, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone. A new guy here.

I've a question to ask.
What is the type of data exchange between the nodes? is it **synchronous** or **asynchronous**?

My regards..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49586/communication-between-nodes/) by [UnNaMeD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3709/unnamed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depends. Topics are asynchronous, services are synchronous and with actions you can chose. The [ROS Introducton](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Introduction) on the wiki provides more information.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3